# Which ESRI license is needed for >4gb rdbms for 1 user?

Tags: arcgis-server, license

I want to create our >4GB geodatabases that interface with our business SQL Server databases.  Essentially create enterprise geodatabases.  Can this be done with a Standard desktop license without need for arcGIS Enterprise (Server)?

We would not need a multi-user editing environment.

Comment: Prob better off asking ESRI.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions regarding commercial licenses should be made direct to the vendor (Esri)

Comment: The ceiling on Express databases moved from 4Gb to 10Gb,  but you seem to want an enterprise geodatabase, for which an ArcGIS Server license is required.

Comment: I did not know that the ceiling was raised to 10GB for express.  Great to know.  But can I connect to our SQL Server databases through an SQL express limited geoDB?  I'm assuming this would be possible using the Basic license?

Answer (score 1):

To test whether this will meet your requirements, which you have only described superficially, you could install and test Database Server (Desktop) [formerly known as ArcSDE Personal] using the [Database Server (Desktop) installation guide](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/install/database-server-desktop-engine/intro-desktop-database-server-installation.htm).